# Maintaining record selection across pages CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

Is there a way to have user selected records remain selected as the pages are changed in the view? Currently, when changing pages in the view, the selection is lost.

For example, the user is looking at the Accounts entity, and wishes to select a few records from the first page of results and other records from subsequent pages.

I have explained that this is standard behaviour and that they should further filter their results but they are insisting that I try to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a supported solution to your problem other than writing custom web-resource pages that will do exactly what you need.

I'm sure you've already told them to set their "records per page" to 250 in their Preferences.

In CRM 4.0, I once figured out where this "records per page" setting is stored in the database and I was able to change it to 5000 directly in the database. It did work (I think I had to iisreset as well), but it is obviously unsupported and could cause massive performance issues.